# How to use a terminal command line in a launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using Hector mapping with a hokuyo laser scanner.
In the launch file of Hector mapping, I added the hokuyo_node for the laserscanner and I also start RVIZ.
But I still need to configure the hokuyo lasserscanner everytime manually in the terminal with this code before starting:
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0

Is there a way to include this in my launch file?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228702/how-to-use-a-terminal-command-line-in-a-launch-file/) by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty sure roslaunch can't handle this because it's simply XML tags (please correct me if I'm wrong) but you should definitely look into setting udev rules for your laser scanner. This means that whenever it's plugged in, the computer will automatically give it proper permissions.

---

Originally posted by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) with karma: 194 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-10**:
@alee is right. See the linked questions in the answer to [Rosrun as super user](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user/).

**Comment by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on 2016-03-10**:
Thanks!

I used this command and my problem is solved: sudo adduser myusername dialout

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-10**:
@Bert: please accept @alee's answer by ticking the checkmark to the left of it.